# Unity 3d рендер моделей, отражения

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d, blender

Есть моделька нужная, но когда переношу её в Unity - она сверкает отражением как металлическая. Как можно сделать на неё освещение послабее? Не теряя в освещении в основном пространстве.

Моделька низкополигональная, поэтому выглядит неприглядно. Можно как нибудь в автоматическом режиме сделать её более гладкой? Из инструментария blender и unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить модификатор subsurf(hotkey: Ctrl + цифра от 1 до 9). Но 1 итерация разбивает каждый полигон на 4.

И включи сглаживание шейдера, если не включено, в tool панели.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень рад что помог.